# Can I store and access files in a Sonatype nexus3 repository like i would do on github or gitlab?

Tags: github, gitlab, repository, registry, nexus3

I'm comparing different Registries and Repositories at the moment.
Can anybody tell me how to store and access files in a Sonatype nexus3 repository?
Not pretty sure this is possible at all due to the fact nexus3 has another focus..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- [browse artifacts in Nexus 3](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/user-interface/browsing-repositories-and-repository-groups) like you would on github.com
- get an artifact [through Nexus API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api#ComponentsAPI-GetComponent) like you would [for GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents).

The difference being in the nature of the artifact browsed/fetched:

- a binary or large file for Nexus 3
- a source code or small static binary for GitHub.